# process a delimited text file with sed

Tags: regex, sed

I have a ";" delimited file:

```
aa;;;;aa
rgg;;;;fdg
aff;sfg;;;fasg
sfaf;sdfas;;;           
ASFGF;;;;fasg
QFA;DSGS;;DSFAG;fagf
```

I'd like to process it replacing the missing value with a `\N` .
The result should be:

```
aa;\N;\N;\N;aa
rgg;\N;\N;\N;fdg
aff;sfg;\N;\N;fasg
sfaf;sdfas;\N;\N;\N         
ASFGF;\N;\N;\N;fasg
QFA;DSGS;\N;DSFAG;fagf
```

I'm trying to do it with a sed script:

```
sed "s/;\(;\)/;\\N\1/g" file1.txt  >file2.txt
```

But what I get is

```
aa;\N;;\N;aa
rgg;\N;;\N;fdg
aff;sfg;\N;;fasg
sfaf;sdfas;\N;;         
ASFGF;\N;;\N;fasg
QFA;DSGS;\N;DSFAG;fagf
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to enclose the second semicolon in parentheses just to use it as `\1` in the replacement string. You can use `;` in the replacement string:

```
sed 's/;;/;\\N;/g'
```

As you noticed, when it finds a pair of semicolons it replaces it with the desired string then skips over it, not reading the second semicolon again and this makes it insert `\N` after every two semicolons.

A solution is to use positive lookaheads; the `regex` is [`/;(?=;)/`](https://regex101.com/r/dB3iI6/1) but `sed` doesn't support them.

But it's possible to solve the problem using `sed` in a simple manner: duplicate the search command; the first command replaces the odd appearances of `;;` with `;\N`, the second one takes care of the even appearances. The final result is the one you need.

The command is as simple as:

```
sed 's/;;/;\\N;/g;s/;;/;\\N;/g'
```

It duplicates the previous command and uses the `;` between `g` and `s` to separe them. Alternatively you can use the `-e` command line option once for each search expression:

```
sed -e 's/;;/;\\N;/g' -e 's/;;/;\\N;/g'
```

---

**Update:**

The OP asks in a comment *"What if my file have 100 columns?"*

Let's try and see if it works:

```
$ echo "0;1;;2;;;3;;;;4;;;;;5;;;;;;6;;;;;;;" | sed 's/;;/;\\N;/g;s/;;/;\\N;/g'
0;1;\N;2;\N;\N;3;\N;\N;\N;4;\N;\N;\N;\N;5;\N;\N;\N;\N;\N;6;\N;\N;\N;\N;\N;\N;
```

Look, ma! It works!
:-)

---

**Update #2**

I ignored the fact that the question doesn't ask to replace `;;` with something else but to replace the empty/missing values in a file that uses `;` to separate the columns. Accordingly, my expression doesn't fix the missing value when it occurs at the beginning or at the end of the line.

As the OP kindly added in a comment, the complete `sed` command is:

```
sed 's/;;/;\\N;/g;s/;;/;\\N;/g;s/^;/\\N;/g;s/;$/;\\N/g'
```

or (for readability):

```
sed -e 's/;;/;\\N;/g;' -e 's/;;/;\\N;/g;' -e 's/^;/\\N;/g' -e 's/;$/;\\N/g'
```

The two additional steps replace ';' when they found it at beginning or at the end of line.

Comment: What if my file have 100 columns?

Comment: Indeed, two pass should suffice!

Comment: At this poin you can add also the solution for the start of the line "s/^;/\\N;/g"  ;)

Comment: You are right. I updated the answer. The last two expressions could be merged but `sed` is not very `regex`-friendly and requires escaping `(`, `)` and also `|`, I think. I couldn't make it work and even if I could, the expression becomes cluttered with backslashes. It looks better this way :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can use this `sed` command with 2 `s` (substitute) commands:

```
sed 's/;;/;\\N;/g; s/;;/;\\N;/g;' file
aa;\N;\N;\N;aa
rgg;\N;\N;\N;fdg
aff;sfg;\N;\N;fasg
sfaf;sdfas;\N;\N;
ASFGF;\N;\N;\N;fasg
QFA;DSGS;\N;DSFAG;fagf
```

Or using **lookarounds regex** in a `perl` command:

```
perl -pe 's/(?<=;)(?=;)/\\N/g' file
aa;\N;\N;\N;aa
rgg;\N;\N;\N;fdg
aff;sfg;\N;\N;fasg
sfaf;sdfas;\N;\N;
ASFGF;\N;\N;\N;fasg
QFA;DSGS;\N;DSFAG;fagf
```

Comment: @dax90: Did I not provide exact same `sed` command in my answer few minutes before the accepted answer?

Comment: Thank you very mutch for your help. Your command works good, infact I give you a "+1" . Anyway I found the accepted answer more complete. Sorry

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is that you can't use several times the same characters for a single replacement:

`s/;;/..../g`: The second `;` can't be reused for the next match in a string like `;;;`

If you want to do it with sed without to use a Perl-like regex mode, you can use a loop with the conditional command `t`:

```
sed ':a;s/;;/;\\N;/g;ta;' file
```

`:a` defines a label "a", `ta` go to this label only if something has been replaced.

For the `;` at the end of the line (and to deal with eventual trailing whitespaces):

```
sed ':a;s/;;/;\\N;/g;ta; s/;[ \t\r]*$/;\\N/1' file
```

Comment: Nice solution. On `OSX` it doesn't work for some obscure reason (but it also doesn't complain of any error). However it works if the `:a` function is extracted in a separate expression: `sed -e ':a' -e 's/;;/;\\N;/g;ta'`.

Comment: no caracter possible after a label in posix (and OSX) version. so `:a` and `t a` could not have a `;` after

Answer (score 1):

this awk one-liner will give you what you want:

```
awk -F';' -v OFS=';' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i=="")$i="\\N"}7' file
```

if you really want the line: `sfaf;sdfas;\N;\N;\N` , this line works for you:

```
awk -F';' -v OFS=';' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i=="")$i="\\N";sub(/;$/,";\\N")}7' file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/;/;\\N/g;s/;\\N\([^;]\)/;\1/g;s/;[[:blank:]]*$/;\\N/' YourFile
```

- non recursive, onliner, posix compliant

Concept:

- change all `;`
- put back unmatched one
- add the special case of last `;` with eventually space before the end of line

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':;s/^(;)|(;);|(;)$/\2\3\\N\1\2/g;t' file
```

There are 4 senarios in which an empty field may occur: at the start of a record, between 2 field delimiters, an empty field following an empty field and at the end of a record. Alternation can be employed to cater for senarios 1,2 and 4 and senario 3 can be catered for by a second pass using a loop (`:;...;t`). Multiple senarios can be replaced in both passes using the `g` flag.